# Kubernetes: How to setup sticky session with AWS loadbalancing

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

Trying to understand how sticky session should be configured when working with service type=loadbalancer in AWS
My backend are 2 pods running tomcat app
I see that the service create the AWS LB as well and I set the right cookie value in the AWS LB configuration ,but when accessing the system I see that I keep switching between my pods/tomcat instances

My service configuration

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
 annotations:
   service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: http
 labels:
   app: app1
 name: AWSELB
 namespace: local
spec:
 type: LoadBalancer
 ports:
 - port: 8080
   targetPort: 8080
 selector:
   app: app1
```

Is there any additional settings that are missing?
Thank you
Jack

Answer (score 1):

Can you try setting Client-IP based session affinity by setting service.spec.sessionAffinity to "ClientIP" (the default is "None"). (http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/services/)

You can also try running an ingress controller which can better manage the routing internal, see: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/13892#issuecomment-223731222

Comment: ClientIP value for sessionAffinity is not supported when service type is LoadBalancer. Do you have an example how to use the ingress controller for L7 routing?

Comment: Ahh you're correct, sorry about that. You can read about ingress here: http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/ingress/

Answer (score 1):

It's not supported. Please see https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/2867 which has the gory details.

Answer (score -1):

kube proxy is L4. If your source IP is the same, you can't distinguish clients. You need a L7 proxy to read those details. Check Ingress: https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress/tree/master/examples/affinity/cookie/nginx
This uses cookies to identify your user and skips the L4 kube-proxy invoking the pod directly.